# Multi-purpose Installer?

Tags: usb-installation

I'd like to have a USB stick that is capable of installing both Windows 10 and Ubuntu (and if possible boot into Ubuntu) with maybe a sort of menu to choose the installer to run.
Is there any way to do this

(Purpose: I have one USB stick, I do a lot of computer stuff, including OS installs. Ubuntu happens to be one of my personal choices of OS)

Comment: I like to have a full install of Ubuntu on a larger flash drive and then add ISO for grub to loop mount. But trying to have Windows on same flash drive is more difficult than the cost of another flash drive. Windows made it a bit more difficult now that its .wim file is over 4GB and does not fit on a FAT32 flash drive. The Windows tool to create an installer splits the .wim file. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot
examples
https://gist.github.com/Pysis868/27203177bdef15fbb70c There are lots of tools that automate the process, but I prefer to do it myself.

Comment: Windows has changed quite a bit since 2017, the ISO is now over 4GB, too big for a FAT32 partition.mkusb-plug works great for making a Windows installer, I have not had success making a flash drive that will install both Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: @Melebius: Sounds interesting, Have you tried that method?

Comment: @C.S.Cameron No, I just use YUMI for *ubuntu + Clonezilla.

Comment: Oops! I just remembered Ventoy.

Comment: @Melebius: This question says nothing about UEFI only Bootable USB as does the old, old question you say is duplicated. As a matter of fact this question asks nothing about installing **Windows 8.1** which is the subject of the other question. The other question does not even work with Windows 10. I am wondering if any of the other people who voted to close this question even read the other question.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Please avoid editing question and adding *"the duplicate target doesn't answer the question"* unless the author intervenes. Readers/future visitors who don't know about site's working may perceive that the edits were done by author themselves. If you think, question is not a duplicate, please leave a comment for reviewers and [edit] question **without** changing the meaning and claiming the target didn't work without any input from author. I see that you've already posted an answer on the target question, so I think that is no more "outdated".

Comment: @Kulfy: This question is not a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/599834/create-uefi-bootable-usb-stick-to-install-windows-and-ubuntu-from-it. Have you looked at the answer on the "target"? It concerns Windows 8. The YUMI site says: "Drive must be FAT32 formatted if you want to UEFI boot".FAT32 has max 4GB file size, too small for a Windows 10 ISO..

Comment: @C.S.Cameron At the end of my previous comment, I've already stated: *I see that you've already posted an answer on the target question, so I think that is no more "outdated"*

Comment: @Kulfy That answer was not there until this answer was shut down.

Comment: @Kulfy To make matters worse, The latest version of YUMI no longer has the problem mentioned in the duplicated thread. Both Windows and Linux work fine in the latest YUMI BIOS/UEFI multiboot without a complex workaround. Perhaps it is not good to offer a fix when nothing is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ventoy

**Ventoy** is installed to a USB disk.

After installation OS ISO's can be copy/pasted, dragged/dropped to the USB.

No further setup is required, unless adding persistence.

MS Windows installer disks can be be added.

Linux OS can be added.

FreeBSD, etc, etc can be added.

90%+ distros in distrowatch.com are supported.
550+ ISO files are tested.

There is Windows and Linux versions.

It is simpler to use than Etcher.

https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html

(sounds good but I prefer mkusb for it's hackability).

### YUMI (The subject of the "Duplicated" Question)

**YUMI** has many loyal users.

It appears that YUMI is still well supported and kept up to date.

Have just tested the latest version YUMI-UEFI-0.0.2.7.

Preformatted the USB to NTFS, started YUMI and installed Windows-1909 installation ISO.

Then installed Ubuntu 20.04.1. (I think Windows should be installed first).

Both items installed and ran without problem. The NTFS USB worked in UEFI mode.

**No workaround was required as shown in a previous answer to the duplicated question.**

YUMI still lags Ventoy as Persistence is limited to 4GB Max. Also YUMI still needs to be run each time a new ISO is added.