# PC won't boot from USB stick

Tags: boot, usb

For some reason, my PC won't boot from usb stick. I've already done it in the past, but it's not working now. I should say that I'm no expert in the subject.

I have Ubuntu 20.04 as the only OS in the PC. now I have to install Windows 10. I created a bootable Windows 10 USB stick and I've already set the booting order in the BIOS, but it simply won't work.

I have used differente programs to create the bootable device (bootable disc creator and UNetBootin), I have tryed different USB ports, I have used different USB sticks, I've formatted them to both FAT32 and NTFS systems, I have changed the BIOS mode to both Legacy and UEFI. Nothing works.
The problem isn't the .iso file either, 'cause I've tried it in a VM and it works just fine.

When I create the bootable USB stick with Bootable Disc Creator: in the Legacy mode it just starts Ubuntu normally, as if there was no flash drive inserted. And in the UEFI mode, it just shows me a message saying "no bootable device found".
When I create it with UNetBootin, a UnetBootin message appears with a command line available. But nothing seems to work and I just end up restarting the pc again and again.

Can anyone help me out here, 'cause at this point I'm extremely frustrated...

Edit:
Now I'm getting this message when I try to boot from the USB drive:

"SYSLINUX 6.04 EDD 20191223 Copyright (C) 1994-2015 H. Peter Anvin et al".

This message only shows up when I create the bootable device with UNetBootin.

---

I'm using a Windows 10 ISO.

This is the output of the command you suggested (sudo parted -l):

[image]

I just realized it's in Portuguese... Modelo = Model. Disco = Disc. Tamanho do setor = Sector Size. Tabela de partição = Partition table. Opções = options. Número = Number. Início = beggining. Fim = End. Tamanho = Size. Tipo = Type. Sistema de arquivos = File System.

Comment: What ISO did you use to create the bootable USB stick? When you boot into Ubuntu are you in UEFI or Legacy mode? With the USB stick inserted run `sudo parted -l` and post output into question.

Comment: So you are trying to create a Windows 10 bootable USB?

Comment: @Dj Quaresma I can follow Portuguese. So sdb is your USB drive, about 4GB? I don't think that's a big enough size. My Win10 USB drive uses 4.3 GB. Please confirm.

Comment: Working from Ubuntu I have had best luck using **mkusb-plug** or **Ventoy** for making the Windows Installer USB, See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274878/make-windows-10-bootable-usb-in-ubuntu/1274975#1274975 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272040/multi-purpose-installer/1272618#1272618 UNetbootin and Startup Disk Creator have not worked for me making a Windows install disk.